# Load all views related to tab bar controller by hard code

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to jump from a viewController to the first viewController related to Tab Bar Controller through code.

The tabBarController Scene has storyboard id `tabView`.

I'm working on this way:

```
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let vc: UITabBarController!
            storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabView")

            vc=storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabView") as! UITabBarController
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                self.present(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

But it loads only the first viewController (out of 5) without the tab bar related to. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this code looks so wrong.

1. In your storyboard give and "tabView" ID to the TabBarController, not the ViewController inside it.
2. Why you are double instantiating ViewController? just do it once and assign it to the vc variable.
3. Why you've created delay before presenting the VC? It's some sort of workaround of something?

Working code:

```
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabView") as! UITabBarController
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: No, it still load only the first viewController related to the tab bar without showing this last one. I've controlled that the tabView ID was given to the TabBarController and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

(1)if you want to navigate from `Appdelegate`

```
     let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate as! AppDelegate
     let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let tabBar = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! TabBarController
     appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
     appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

(2)if you want to navigate from `viewcontroller` which has root of navigation

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
```

Comment: In the first case, I've no window attribute in my viewController class.
In the second, there's no method with that name defined.